# ActionScript - setTextFormat() More Than Once on Same String?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, format, set

i'm unsuccessfully attempting to assign a textFormat to two different parts of the same string, but the second time it doesn't register and remains the default text format.  both styles (regular and bold) of the font are embedded.

```
//Create Text Field
private function createAboutWindowTextField():TextField
    {
    var aboutWindowFont:Font = new AboutWindowFont();

    var regularFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    var boldFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

    regularFormat.size = boldFormat.size = 12;
    regularFormat.font = boldFormat.font = aboutWindowFont.fontName;
    regularFormat.align = boldFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
    boldFormat.bold = true;

    var result:TextField = new TextField();
    result.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
    result.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    result.defaultTextFormat = regularFormat;
    result.embedFonts = true;
    result.multiline = true;
    result.selectable = false;
    result.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;

    result.text =   "First Header\n" +
                    "Version 1.0\n" +                                                           
                    "Copyright © 2011\n\n" +

                    "Second Header:\n" +
                    "Other info";                                                       

    result.setTextFormat(boldFormat, result.text.indexOf("First Header"), ("First Header").length);
    result.setTextFormat(boldFormat, result.text.indexOf("Second Header:"), ("Second Header:").length);

    return result;
    }
```

the above code should result in both "First Header" and "Second Header:" becoming bold, but only "First Header" will be set as bold while "Second Header:" seems to be simply ignored.  what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter on your setTextFormat function is incorrect. You're using length when you want to get the ending index. Like this:

```js
var indexA:int = result.text.indexOf("Second Header:");
result.setTextFormat(boldFormat, indexA, indexA + ("Second Header:").length);
```

I like to use [StyleSheet](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html) to format a textfield with multiple fonts or font weights. It's a bit easier to manage.

```js
var reg:HelveticaReg = new HelveticaReg();
var bold:HelveticaBold = new HelveticaBold();

var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat(reg.fontName, 14, 0x000000);

var ss:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
ss.setStyle(".bold", {fontFamily:bold.fontName});

var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.width = 400;
tf.multiline = true;
tf.wordWrap = true;
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tf.selectable = false;
tf.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
tf.embedFonts = true;
tf.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
tf.defaultTextFormat = format;
tf.styleSheet = ss;
tf.htmlText = "<span class='bold'>Lorem ipsum dolor</span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
addChild(tf);
```

Comment: are you saying it's not possible to apply multiple instances of the same textFormat to a textField without using StyleSheet and HTMLText?

Comment: I added an example of the StyleSheet solution. In my tests, I am able to apply the text format to multiple sections of the text field. Maybe try using a different font for the Bold font rather than setting "bold=true" in your text format. For testing, if you change the color of the bold format, do the colors change correctly?

Comment: no, setting the bold font to a different color doesn't apply the 2nd time either.  strangely, if i only apply it once and try to set the text format to result.text.indexOf("Second Header:") it will not be applied either.  i wonder if the problem is with the string?  tracing result.text.indexOf("Second Header:") returns the correct index.

Comment: Thats odd. What if you input the index numbers manually? Same result?

Comment: yes, same result.  since htmltext/stylesheet works for me i'll just use that.  but i think something so simple that seems to require htmltext and a style sheet is ludicrous.  also, i had to add the font weight to your code to make it work:  ss.setStyle(".bold", {fontFamily: bold.fontName, fontWeight: "bold"});

Comment: omg.  i'm ssooooo stupid!  lol.  i can't believe i did that.  thank you for solving the mystery.